# Combining three nested lists without increasing number of sublists

Tags: python

As a part of a bigger program that creates "fair" teams for sport activities, I need to combine three nested lists in python in a special way. I want to add the shortest sublist of e.g. list1 to the longest sublist of list2 so that my output is a nested list where e.g. new_sublist 1 consists of one sublist from each previous lists with the length of the new_sublists being roughly the same.

Example:

```
list1 = [["Peter","Anne"],["Maria"],["Max"]]
list2 = [["John","Jacob"],["Grace"],["Clara"]]
```

The output should look like this:

```
final_list = [["Peter","Anne","Grace"],["Maria","John","Jacob"],["Max","Clara"]]
```

Simply combining the lists using `.extend` or `.append` does not work for me, since it does not combine the different sublists but rather just adds new sublists to the existing nested list.

Comment: You can use `shortest_sublist = min(list1, key=len)` and `longest_sublist = max(list2, key=len)` to find the longest from one side and the shortest from the other side and work with that. Once you use one element remove it from the lists.

Comment: Keep in mind though, if you were to add another single name in a list, like `list2 = [["John", "Jacob"], ["Grace"], ["Clara"], ["Clara2"]]` you'd end up with poor Clara2 left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Sort both outer lists by length of inner elements, one ascending and one descending

Step 2. Zip respective elements of both lists together.

```
list1 = [["Peter","Anne"],["Maria"],["Max"]]
list2 = [["John","Jacob"],["Grace"],["Clara"]]
ls1 = sorted(list1, key=len)
ls2 = sorted(list2, key=len, reverse=True)
res = [el1 + el2 for el1, el2 in zip(ls1, ls2)]
print(res) # [['Maria', 'John', 'Jacob'], ['Max', 'Grace'], ['Peter', 'Anne', 'Clara']]
```

Comment: This will miss elements if the lists are not the same length, also if one sublist is longer that the others by a lot the condition of `creates "fair" teams` is not met.

Comment: I don't really see another way to meet the condition of adding one sublist from each of the lists.

Comment: OP does say `I need to combine **three** nested lists` so maybe I'm just overcomplicating things thinking of variable length lists.

Comment: Seems like a fair approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I see to solve your problem.

`number_of_teams` is important so figure out how you want to distribute the teams.

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4], [5], [6], [8,9], [10]]
list2 = [[11,12], [13], [14], [15]]

# You said without increasing number of sublists so I went with using the maximum number of sublists
# You could use min() or a random number between min() and max() or an even number that's below max()
# an even number that's below max() is probably the best answer since you're supposed to make sports teams
number_of_teams = max(len(list1), len(list2))

print(f"Creating {number_of_teams} teams.")

flat_list1 = [item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]
flat_list2 = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist]

final_flat_list = flat_list1 + flat_list2

# Calculate the target length for each sublist
total_elements = len(final_flat_list)
target_len = total_elements // number_of_teams

fair_distribution = []

start = 0
# How many teams need an additional member
remainder = total_elements % number_of_teams

print(f"Divinding {total_elements} players in {number_of_teams} teams we find that there's {remainder} players left to distribute")

for i in range(number_of_teams):
    # While there's a player left to distribute, add it to the current team.
    additional_element = 1 if i < remainder else 0
    end = start + target_len + additional_element
    sublist = final_flat_list[start:end]
    start = end
    if additional_element:
        print(f"{sublist[-1]} added to team {i} as extra")
    fair_distribution.append(sublist)

print(fair_distribution)
```

This outputs:

```
Creating 5 teams.
Divinding 14 players in 5 teams we find that there's 4 players left to distribute
3 added to team 0 as extra
6 added to team 1 as extra
10 added to team 2 as extra
13 added to team 3 as extra
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14, 15]]
```